# CSS: 'body' and 'html' set to 'overflow-x: hidden;' and a sticky navbar works but page has extra scrollable whitespace on right

Tags: html, css

Contrary to what I read in [this article](https://blog.cloud66.com/position-sticky-problem/),
I have `html` and `body` set to `overflow-x: hidden;` and their `height` set to `100%`, and my navbar is still displaying correctly as `position: sticky;`. The problem is that there is now extra scrollable whitespace to the right of the page, and I'm not sure how I can get rid of it (this is why I had `overflow-x: hidden;` set on `html` and `body` in the first place).

Interestingly, the article says that `position: sticky;` won't display properly if a parent has `overflow-x: hidden;` or a set `height`, and, if I include just one of those properties, the results are as predicted. But when I include both of them, my navbar displays correctly as `position: sticky;`, but with this new issue.

I've tried including a wrapper around all the content in `body`, but this doesn't make a difference. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

#headerDiv {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #808000;
}

#headerDiv>h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 35px;
  left: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-family: Georgia;
}

#navBar {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #C0392B;
}

#navBar>li {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  right: 50px;
}

#navBar a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: white;
  background-color: #C0392B;
}

#contentDiv {
  height: 500px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-style: double;
  background-color: #FFDEAD;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="headerDiv">
    <h1>Site Heading</h1>
  </div>
  <ul id="navBar">
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="contentDiv">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you try and set width of html and body to some particular value?

Comment: I put your code in [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fepz1ay6/) but I don't see the issue.

Comment: i can't recreate the issue either

Comment: Hi @VipulSharma. I just tried but It hasn't changed anything. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Oh really? Is the navbar still sticking in your case?

Comment: I just looked at the fiddle, and the issue was still there.

Answer (score 1):

The scrollbar on the right is because of overflow Y and not X, add either `overflow:hidden;`

or `overflow-y:hidden;` to your code.

your div content div has height 500px and when the browser gets too small to fit that div inside overflow-y will get activated.

EDIT:

i found a bug in your code, the headerDiv has `width 100%;` but your `#headerDiv > h1` has no width set, this means it will also get width 100%, but you did set a left 25px, wich mean it floats outside since its 100% and gets pushed left 25px. i set the width of `#headerDiv > h1` to `max-width: 80%;` to make it fit

the new code:

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#headerDiv {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #808000;
}

#headerDiv > h1 {
    position: relative;
    max-width:80%;
    top: 35px;
    left: 25px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-family: Georgia;   
}

#navBar {
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 0;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #C0392B;
}

#navBar > li {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    right: 50px;
}

#navBar a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Georgia;
    color: white;
    background-color: #C0392B;
}

#contentDiv {
    height: 500px;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;    
    padding: 20px;
    border-style: double;
    background-color: #FFDEAD;  
}
```

```html
        <div id="headerDiv">
            <h1>Site Heading</h1>
        </div>
        <ul id="navBar">
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="contentDiv">   
        </div>
```

Comment: You beauty! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to give a width too to HTML, body.

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Rahul Yadev. Just tried that, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: I understand that's a bit annoying. Can you create a playground on JSFiddle or  CodePen?

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and I'm not getting any white space to the right. Try opening in Chrome and using the dev tools to inspect the white space and see what is causing your problem.

Here's what I'm getting from your code.No option to scroll to the right and the page fills out 100% of the viewport

[image: What I'm seeing in the browser]

Comment: Hi @seanculleng. I just made `contentDiv` 500px high for the fiddle display. Can you see the problem in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/R_Neville/7y12cx9b/)?